# Search and insert the search results in database in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I've two forms in a single page. One form fetches data from database table. In the other form I need those fetched values to be added in another table, with additional values.

```
<form method="post" action="same.php" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" name="result" value="search_for" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="same.php" name="form2">
<input type="date" name="add_date" />
<input type="submit" name="result" value="search_for" />
</form>
```

After searching I will get values in a variable `$search`.

Now I need to post the variable `$search` in another table, but when I click submit the     search values get null.

Comment: Your form doesn't make sense to most people. If you can explain why you've done this, it might help you get answers. Have you ever encountered a form like this anywhere on the internet? If so, provide an example.
You might want to take a step back and ask a more basic question about what forms are used for, or about how to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: concept is.. "get values from database table and display in a div, then add the div values in the database tables with date". wen i get the values i use submit button to fetch the values, it executes correctly then wen i want to submit the executed values with date it doesnt, reason is the page gets loaded on submit so the form 2 contains null values.. i have used two forms, both uses post method. please tell me solution for this. @Buttle Butkus

Comment: Your real question should maybe be "how to debug PHP"? And "how do forms work?" Why are you displaying both forms on the page at the same time. Can a user use form 2 without using form 1 first? If not, do not display form2 unless the user has already submitted form 1. Just surround the HTML for form2 with `if(isset($_POST['search'])) {}`. Next, add `print_r($_POST)` to the bottom of your page before the `</body>` tag and see what values you are posting.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can do this 
you have only one way to do this is to include all input's in to one form

i think you can do this by 2 way

1. putting all input in one form

or you can do this by making two step as

page 1 contains form one and page2 contain form2 
as follows

page 1

```
<form method="post" action="same.php" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<input type="submit" name="result" value="search_for">
</form>
```

page 2

```
<form method="post" action="same.php" name="form2">
//data from page1 {form1} 
<input type="hidden" name="search" value=<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?> />

//you will not need this
<input type="submit" name="result" value="search_for">

<input type="date" name="add_date"/>
<input type="submit" name="result" value="search_for">
</form>
```